# Converting an int64 value to a Number object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, com, type-conversion, int64

I have a COM object which has a method that returns an unsigned int64 (VT_UI8) value.  We have an HTML page which contains some JavaScript which can load the COM object and make the call to that method, to retrieve the value as such:

```
var foo = MyCOMObject.GetInt64Value();
```

This value can easily be displayed to the user in a message dialog using:

```
alert(foo);
```

or displayed on the page by:

```
document.getElementById('displayToUser').innerHTML = foo;
```

However, we cannot use this value as a Number (e.g. if we try to multiply it by 2) without the page throwing "Number expected" errors.  If we check "typeof(foo)" it returns "unknown".

I've found a workaround for this by doing the following:

```
document.getElementById('displayToUser').innerHTML = foo;
var bar = parseInt(document.getElementById('displayToUser').innerHTML);
alert(bar*2);
```

What I need to know is how to make that process more efficient.  Specifically, is there a way to cast foo to a String explicitly, rather than having to set some document element's innerHTML to foo and then retrieve it from that.  I wouldn't mind calling something like:

```
alert(parseInt((string)foo) * 2);
```

Even better would be if there is a way to directly convert the int64 to a Number, without going through the String conversion, but I hold out less hope for that.

Comment: All numbers are doubles in Javascript. Therefore you should be aware that you might loose some precision by converting your 64bit int to a double.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
alert(Number(String(foo)) * 2);
```

should do it (but **see below**), if your COM object implements `toString` (or `valueOf` with the "string" hint) correctly (and apparently it does, if your `innerHTML` trick works -- because when you assign `foo` to `innerHTML`, the same process of converting the COM object to a string occurs as with `String(foo)`).

From Section 15.5.1 of the 5th Edition ECMAScript spec:

> When String is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it performs a type conversion.

And Section 15.7.1

> When Number is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it performs a type conversion

It may be worth trying just `Number(foo) * 2` to make sure, but I don't think it'll work (it seems like your COM object only handles conversion to String, not Number, which isn't surprising or unreasonable).

---

**Edit** If `String(foo)` is failing, try:

```
alert(Number("" + foo) * 2);
```

I'm **very** surprised that your `innerHTML` trick is working but `String(foo)` is throwing an error. Hopefully `"" + foo` will trigger the same *implicit* conversion as your `innerHTML` trick.

---

**Edit** Okay, this COM object is being very strange indeed. My next two salvos:

```
alert(("" + foo) * 2);
```

That uses all implicit conversions (adding an object to a string converts the object to a string; applying the `*` operator to a string converts it to a number).

Alternately, we can make the string->number conversion explicit but indirect:

```
alert(parseInt("" + foo) * 2);
```

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately, calling "String(foo)" yields a "String expected" error.

Comment: @Matt: Try `alert(Number("" + foo) * 2)` instead. (I'm *very* surprised that `String(foo)` doesn't work, but if `innerHTML = foo` works, then `"" + foo` should work.) (Edited my answer to include this.)

Comment: Interesting, the result of that is, apparently, always 0, so that won't work either. Thanks though.

Comment: @Matt: Did you try `alert(parseInt("" + foo) * 2)`? Just in case? (Or, actually, `alert(("" + foo) * 2)` should work -- that's using all implicit conversions.) (Answer edited; maybe it should just be a list of options using strikeout for the ones that didn't work. :-) )

Comment: @TJ Unfortunately those didn't work either.  They both result in "NaN". Thanks for all the help, though!

Comment: @Matt: What's the string version of the number? Are you sure it's not just too big to fit in a Javascript Number? (Although I guess if your `innerHTML` trick works...)

Answer (score 1):

Eek. Well if none of the explicit conversions are working because of the strange behaviour of the host object, let's try the implicit ones:

```
var n= +(''+foo);
```

I'm assuming you don't mind that the target type `Number` doesn't cover the full range of values of an int64 (it's a `double`, so you only get 52 bits of mantissa).

Comment: That results in n being set to 0.  I know Number won't give me the range I need, but it's better than having nothing (especially since I've never seen this particular method return a result that couldn't fit in 32 bits).

Answer (score 0):

Matt, from the comments to other answers, I suspect you're running this code in some sort of loop.  If so, make sure that you check the returned value for null before trying your conversions.

```
var foo = MyCOMObject.GetInt64Value(); 
if (foo == null) {
  foo = 0; // Or something else
}
```